# lazyload images - index images in the search engines

Tags: javascript, html, dom, search, seo

I believe that Google displays the *DOM* also modified by *Javascript*.
Look I used the tool *Fetch as Google/Bing/Baidu*

**Look at the results:**

> Without my jquery-plugin and **noscript** (ie pure HTML):
>
> [image: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2632/webpagethumbnail1.jpg]

---

> With javascript and **noscript**:
>
> [image: http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/3485/webpagethumbnail.jpg]
>
> **note:** The javascript that showcased images and manipulated the DOM.

**LIB Javascript**

Download and test-case: https://github.com/brcontainer/defer-images/

**Question:**

- Use `<noscript>` to help indexing of images is a good?
- If it's a bad idea, give me an example of an HTML good for indexing images and I can use *LazyLoad*.
- If the javascript displays images and *Fetch as Google/Bing/Baidu* displays the content normally (like the browser) so *Google/Bing/Baidu* indexes the DOM manipulated by javascript?

Comment: It's not invalid, the data- attribute is supported by HTML5. Also, "data-original" is an attribute specific to your implementation and not relevant to SEO.

Comment: But this can affect how search engines index the images? (Can problem occurs?)

Comment: Nope, you're fine. Search engines will ignore the data- attributes (especially since they can be different on every site)

Answer (score 2):

The search-engine will index the image `grey.gif`. It will never know about `example.jpg`.

[`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) are valid in HTML5 (only).

PS: Don't forget the `alt` attribute.

Comment: That is only valid in html5 I already know.
My problem is not SEO and validate the HTML.

Do you know any alternative? thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento What is your question exactly?

Comment: If there is an alternative to LazyLoad that does not affect the operation of SEO. I thought about using <noscript>, but still do not know if it will be a good practice. Any suggestions? Thanks